# Getting Empty lines when exporting into SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Whenever I upload the file from excel and export into SQL, I get multiple empty lines(&nbsp)

Below is my code. Can you please let me know how can I avoid this empty line

```
private void BindGrid()
        {
        String Constr = "Data Source=INNN;integrated security=true;InitialCatalog=info";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constr);
        con.Open();
        String SelectQuery = "Select ID,Name,Region,City from Infor";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SelectQuery, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Download.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        this.BindGrid();

        //GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me how can I avoid these empty lines.

```
private void ExportRowsToDB()
    {
        //container for source data
        DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable("Infor");
        //dtProducts.Columns.Add("ID");
        dtProducts.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtProducts.Columns.Add("Region");
        dtProducts.Columns.Add("City");

        DataRow dr = null;
        //iterate through each grid and populate source data
        foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in gvExcelFile.Rows)
        {
            dr = dtProducts.NewRow();
            //dr["ID"] = (gridRow.Cells[1].Text);
            dr["Name"] = gridRow.Cells[1].Text;
            dr["Region"] = gridRow.Cells[2].Text;
            dr["City"] = gridRow.Cells[3].Text;

            dtProducts.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        //insert data into destination table
        CopyData(dtProducts);
    }

    public void CopyData(DataTable sourceData)
    {
        string destConnString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
        // Set up the bulk copy object.
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                           new SqlBulkCopy(destConnString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Infor";
            // Guarantee that columns are mapped correctly by
            // defining the column mappings for the order.    

            //bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Region", "Region");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");

            // Write from the source to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceData);
        }
    }
```

Below is my sql table detail

```
Table Infor(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
FormattedID AS ('CUID' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)),10)),
[Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Region] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[City] [nvarchar](20) NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES RequestInf (ID)
```

Comment: without looking at data its hard to solve your problem. please share the data sample

Comment: Above is my table detail. Could you please help me on this

Comment: "*..I upload the file from excel and export into SQL...*": The code you posted is actually just attempting to export a GridView to Excel by spitting out HTML forced to content type of "application/vnd.ms-excel".

Comment: Sorry I have now pasted the code.

Comment: Can someone help me, How can I avoid empty lines when exporting

Comment: Could you please help me, How can I avoid empty lines when exporting

Answer (score 0):

Add a "where" for the length of the first column

```
 String SelectQuery = "Select ID,Name,Region,City from Infor WHERE Len(F1) > 0";
```